# Url Hack for Report/Dashboard

Tags: reporting, urlhacking

I tried to create a Url Hack with the Name of the logged in User in Salesforce Lightning, but It does n't work.

REPORT
[https://mydomain.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Report/00O67000006T4X2EAK/view?fv0={!User.Name}](https://mydomain.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Report/00O67000006T4X2EAK/view?fv0=%7B!User.Name%7D)

--> Url if I run the Link
https://mydomain.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Report/00O67000006T4X2EAK/view?fv0=%7B%21User.Name%7D

DASHBOARD
[https://mydomain.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Dashboard/01Z670000005tvBEAQ/view?queryScope=userFolders&fv0={!User.Name}](https://mydomain.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Dashboard/01Z670000005tvBEAQ/view?queryScope=userFolders&fv0=%7B!User.Name%7D)

--> Url if run the Link
https://mydomain.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Dashboard/01Z670000005tvBEAQ/view?queryScope=userFolders&fv0=%7B%21User.Name%7D

Any Ideas? What I doing wrong.

Comment: Not sure where this link is created, is it a component? Did you mean to use `$User` instead of `User`?

Comment: I tried this also, but If I run it with {$User.Name} at the end of the url -- > a new window open with the link but the end is change to %7B%24User.Name%7D